# External JavaScript dependencies in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, npm, webpack-dev-server

I have read a few Q/A on here on how to use external libraries in TS. Following a lot of the suggestions, I'm registering BT alert to an element like this:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

window["$"] = $;
window["jQuery"] = $;

$("#clientAlert").alert();
```

and everything work just fine.

Now I need to do the same for JQuery-Ticker

```
import * as jqueryTicker from "jquery-ticker";
$('.newsticker').ticker();
```

WebPack build fails with this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'ticker' does not exist on type
>   'JQuery'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast it to `<any>` or extend the jquery typing to add your own method.

```
 (<any>$(".newsticker")).ticker();
```

//Or add your own custom methods (Assuming this is added by yourself as a part of custom plugin)

```
interface JQuery {
    newsticker():void;
}
```

Or this

```
($(".newsticker") as any).ticker();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
($(".newsticker") as any).ticker();
```